# Using Requests library with WSGI

Tags: python, heroku, python-requests, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm creating a GroupMe bot that's hosted on Heroku with Gunicorn as the WSGI server.
When I try deploying the app, I get a `failed to find object 'app' in 'MODULE_NAME' error`, I think because I don't have a WSGI callable.

Here's what I have:

```css
 def app():
 while True:
  rqResponse = requests.get('https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/' + groupID +'/messages', params = requestParams)

  # Pings the gm-membot Heroku app so it doesn't idle.
  requests.get('http://gm-bot.herokuapp.com') 

  if rqResponse.status_code == 200:
    gotten = rqResponse.json()['response']['messages']
    
    for message in gotten:
      messageText = message['text'].lower()
      if (messageText in bot_reply.staticTriggers) or (messageText in bot_reply.dynamicTriggers):
        bot_reply.botReply(message)             
        
      requestParams['since_id'] = message['id']

      else:
        raise Exception('error')
        break

  time.sleep(5)
```

My Procfile output:

```
web: gunicorn MODULE_NAME:app --workers=1
```

However, After looking at the documentation for Gunicorn and WSGI, I can't figure out how to mesh it with the code I already have written using the Requests library. Is there any way I can get Gunicorn to work without a lot of rewriting? Also, I'm very new to this, so I apologize if there's an obvious answer.

(P.S. everything works fine if I just host the app on my latptop!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two answers: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55194634/11647025) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50157417/11647025), though I think it's the memory leak on server (cause you said hosted local everything works).

Try and let me know

Comment: I think changing the filename worked! At least, I'm getting a new error message. (`at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=gm-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=b4b503a1-fb93-4a45-974a-021c6e5bddcc fwd="52.87.225.29" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http`)

Comment: Glad it worked! Btw going to http://gm-bot.herokuapp.com/ I got an application error, I think that's the reason you got 503 error (response: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command `heroku logs --tail`)