# gcloud crontab calling appengine twice per invocation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron, cloud

Im using google cloud crontab service to schedule a execution call to my appengine deployment but the application gets called twice every time.

If I look at the logs for the execution they look like :

```sh
A 2019-08-01T07:45:57.863504Z [2019-08-01 07:45:57 +0000] [8] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load. 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:57.863464Z [2019-08-01 07:45:57 +0000] [8] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:57.738421Z [2019-08-01 07:45:57 +0000] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23) 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:57.738255Z Failed to find application object 'app' in 'main' 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:57.690684Z [2019-08-01 07:45:57 +0000] [27] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 27) 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:57.690578Z Failed to find application object 'app' in 'main' 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:55.437836Z [2019-08-01 07:45:55 +0000] [27] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:55.308841Z [2019-08-01 07:45:55 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:55.200388Z [2019-08-01 07:45:55 +0000] [8] [INFO] Using worker: threads 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:55.200363Z [2019-08-01 07:45:55 +0000] [8] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (8) 
A 2019-08-01T07:45:55.196688Z [2019-08-01 07:45:55 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0 
I 2019-08-01T07:45:53.869998Z GET 502 320 B 3,9 s AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) / GET 502 320 B 3,9 s AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) 5d4298b100ff0d466ecf07b28f0001657e717765657274796461696c790001323031393038303174303933323337000100
```

Here you can see two workers(pid 27,23) are started every time even though I didn't specify that.

My cron.yaml looks like:

```sh
cron:
    - description: "regular job"
      url: /daily
      schedule: every day 21:10
```

And just in case its needed my app.yaml:

```sh
runtime: python37
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto

includes:
- credentials.yaml
```

The application runs once if I test it locally so its definitely on google side(something with the yamls). The code for the full app is here https://github.com/jiwidi/DailyQwertee/blob/master/gcloud-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging entries shows a 502 error at the bottom of your screenshot, which indicates that the Cron job did call the application, but the error is actually thrown by the application itself. Under each of the worker entries you have pointed out, there is a “Failed to find application object ‘app’ in ‘main’ “ entry, which you can fix by following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157243/error-gunicorn-failed-to-find-application-object-app-in-app/50157417).