# Gunicorn : Failed to find application object 'App' in 'run'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

Trying to run a flask app in Gunicorn but I am getting the following error

**Failed to find application object 'App' in 'run'**

**run.py**

```
import app as flask_app
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = flask_app.factory.create_app(celery=flask_app.celery)
    App.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Command to run the app using gunicorn

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5100 run:App`

Could someone please tell me the possible cause and solution? If I've missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point, let me know in the comments.

I have also referred [Error: gunicorn: Failed to find application object 'app' in 'app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157243/error-gunicorn-failed-to-find-application-object-app-in-app]) but was not able to get a possible solution on changing the filename as mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App` needs to be on the top level scope:

```py
import app as flask_app
import os

App = flask_app.factory.create_app(celery=flask_app.celery)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: You saved my day. Can I know what is why is so or any reference for the same

Comment: Because your conditional statement makes big difference. If you run gunicorn like this gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5100 run:App it will look for App from run but given you put __name__ == '__main__', that condition will fail and gunicorn will give error.

Comment: '__name__' will be  '__main__' when run 'run.py' like python run.py in other cases it will be different